# "TypeError: response.pipe is not a function" in Node.js

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require("http");
const zlib = require('zlib');

function requestuest_Handler(request,response) {

    console.log("HTTP requestuest recieved Method : " +request.method);
    var requestBody = [];
    request.on('data', function (chunk) {
        requestBody.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', function () {  
    if (request.method == 'POST')
    {
        console.log("Content-Encoding : " + request.headers['content-encoding']);

        if (request.headers['content-encoding'] == 'gzip')
        {
            gunzipJSON(requestBody);
            /*var body = requestBody;
            zlib.gunzip(requestBody, function(error, data)
            {
                if(!error) {
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip' });
                requestBody = data.toString();
                console.log("Final request Body : " + requestBody);
            } else {
            console.log("Error unzipping:");
            console.log(error);
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.end();
            }               
        });*/
        } else {
        console.log("requestuest Not Encoded");
        }
    }
    });
}

// Function to Decode "gzip" encoded Data

function gunzipJSON (response)
{    
    var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
    var json = "";

    gunzip.on('data', function(data){
        json += data.toString();
    });

    gunzip.on('end', function(){
    parseJSON(json);
    });

    response.pipe(gunzip);
    //console.log("final Decoded Data : " +final_res);
}

// Function to parse JSON Object
function parseJSON(json)
{    
    var json = JSON.parse(json);

    if(json.items.length){    
       for(var i in json.items){    
        console.log(json.items[i].title + '\n' + json.items[i].link);    
    }    
    }
}

console.log("Starting HTTP Server ...");
var server = http.createServer(requestuest_Handler).listen(10080);
```

Comment: 1. Please be more verbose 2. Please properly indent code

Comment: because you passed `requestBody` in `gunzipJSON` and `requestBody` is an array that, I think, doesn't support `pipe` .